# Python with Imagemagick

Tags: python, imagemagick

I want to write a Python code using ImageMagick library that would take an input image and output an image which has a large emoji on it at the center of the original image. The emoji should be randomly selected each time the code runs.

Though I am able to put a specific emoji but selecting a random emoji is difficult I guess. For that I wrote a code:

```
import urllib2

from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display


fg_url = 'http://emojidictionary.emojifoundation.com/img/emoji50.jpg'
bg_url = 'http://www.camp4joy.narod.ru/Na/Nature-259.jpg'

bg = urllib2.urlopen(bg_url)
with Image(file=bg) as bg_img:
    fg = urllib2.urlopen(fg_url)
    with Image(file=fg) as fg_img:
        bg_img.composite(fg_img, left=214, top=160)
    fg.close()
    display(bg_img)
bg.close()
```

Comment: `fg_url = 'http://emojidictionary.emojifoundation.com/img/emoji{}.jpg'.format(random.randint(1, 800))` (Import `random` module)

Comment: Thank you very much @falsetru. Now it's working.